# Migrate php folder to Wordpress

Tags: php, migration, cms, bulk-import, development-strategy

I am redesigning a cms-less, flat file php website and developing it in WordPress.

The existing website is not using a database. One directory in the php site has over 100 pages and the content needs to be imported into WP.

I've created a custom content type for this directory, but does anyone have best practices or tips or plugins to migrate/import such a massive folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that each php file contains the content of a page. It depends a lot on how your content is written in that php page, you should make another php script, go trough all files in that directory.

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Entries:\n";

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    /* This is the WRONG way to loop over the directory. */
    while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Then get the content of each file and find some patterns where your content should be. Get the content with preg_replace and you can add the post with the content.

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'My post',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Make sure you include or require wp_load.php on this script.